# Make_Flaggable - Show User's Flagged Items

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my app I have items and those items can be marked as "favorite" using the [make_flaggable](https://github.com/medihack/make_flaggable) gem.

I'd like to create a page where every user can see his favorite items.

Any help would me much appreciated!

**item.rb**

```
make_flaggable :favorite
```

**user.rb**

```
make_flagger
```

items_controller.rb

```
def favorite
  @current_user = User.first  
  @item = Item.find(params[:id])
  @current_user.flag(@item, :favorite)
  redirect_to @item, :notice => "Added to Your Favorites"
end

def unfavorite
  @current_user = User.first  
  @item = Item.find(params[:id])
  @current_user.unflag(@item, :favorite)
  redirect_to @item, :notice => "Removed from Your Favorites"
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The make_flaggable gem generates a database table that links `flaggables` to `flaggers` with the following schema:

```
flaggings
  flaggable (polymorphic)
  flagger (polymorphic)
  reason
  timestamps
```

And the corresponding model:

```
class MakeFlaggable::Flagging < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :flaggable, :polymorphic => true
  belongs_to :flagger, :polymorphic => true
end
```

When you call `make_flaggable` and `make_flagger`, the following relationships are added to your users and items:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :flaggings, :class_name => "MakeFlaggable::Flagging", :as => :flaggable
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :flaggings, :class_name => "MakeFlaggable::Flagging", :as => :flagger
end
```

So, we want to go through the relationship `User -> Flagging -> Flaggable`. Unfortunately, since the `flaggable` relationship is polymorphic, we **can't** just add to user:

```
has_many :flagables, through: :flaggings
```

However, since you are only flagging items, you can explicitly set the source type:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :flagged_items, :through => :flaggings, :source => :flaggable, :source_type => 'Item'
end
```

Now you can have a controller method like:

```
@current_user = User.first
@items = @current_user.flagged_items
```

Comment: this one seems to work. however, I am only able to create favorites with the first user, any idea?

Comment: In your listed controller code (and mine) you are using `@current_user = User.first` instead of using some sort of user authentication method.

Comment: I want to use make_flaggable gem but not able to install it in rails 3.2.17